# How to create a Hyperledger Fabric REST API

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric2.2

I am tasked with creating an Express Rest API to talk to our AWS Amazon Managed Blockchain Hyper-ledger Fabric network.

I have researched quite a bit, and have seen many different ways to connect to a Hyper-ledger Network. However, it seems none of these are up to date. Even after a few hours of research I have not found a solution that has been updated within the last couple years. I would like to try and use the most current tech available for longevity purposes.

Sidequestion: How much does connecting to AWS Managedblockchain differ from connecting to a self hosted Fabric network?

Thanks in advance!